# How to get request values from Django decorator

Tags: django, decorator

In my decorator:

```
def check_user_identity(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_check_user = mock_response.check_user_identity(requested_data=request.data['msisdn'])
        if response_check_user['status'] == SUCCESS_CODE:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(data=INVALID_USER, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

In my views:
Here the request parameter has my values which i have requested to proceed. First of all decorator is called. I want to access my request data from the decorator.

```
class VerifyWallet(APIView):
    @check_user_identity
    def post(self, request):
        logger.debug(msg=request.data)
        serializer = VerifyWalletSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            logger.error(msg=serializer.errors)
            return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(data='success', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: `request` can be accessed in the decorator, can't be?

Comment: Yes @ArakkalAbu

Comment: *"I want to access my request data from the decorator"*: Then it is solved

Answer (score 0):

After all my searching, i have found the answer. The values is in the args[0].